# Multiple WhatsApp clients on Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, whatsapp

I used to go in terminal and run

```
sudo /Applications/WhatsApp.app/Contents/MacOS/WhatsApp /secondary
```

to load two instances of Whatsapp desktop and work with both my business and home whatsapp simultaneously. Since Big Sur it won't let the second window connect to the internet though.

Any other suggestions on how I could set up a second instance of Whatsapp on my mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you don't have internet on the second instance, but I want to provide an alternative. In your browser, visit web.whatsapp.com and create a window shortcut. It will act like a secondary app.

In any Chromium browser you can do it at **Settings > More Tools > Create Shortcut** then make sure it will be in Window mode.

Comment: Thank you, that was actually a great idea. The window is independent from my Chrome tabs and basically doesn't have any buttons or the address bar to bother. Much better than keeping it on a web whatsapp tab.

Answer (score 0):

That's very helpful but the questions continues to be: why is it so difficult to run two instances of the WhatsApp? is there more to do for it to work?

In my case, it doesn't even open, it's like a faulty app (opens and crashes).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1096275)